# Center of mass of this toppling shape.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on Mechanics 2 for my Mathematics exams and while doing past papers, I am now stuck at this question.

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

To be specific, I cannot seem to do the question 4, part (iii).

Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Please do not tell me the answer, teach me the method.

Comment: One thing would be to determine the combined center of mass of the cone/cylinder object. And then use the condition for an object to topple over under the action of gravity. The COM will be a function of the height of the cylinder

Comment: I know, I did do that. I just don't know how to apply the condition of toppling for this shape. I do know for a triangle

Comment: The condition for toppling is the same for any object that has a base (here the curved side of the cylinder), the condition is that the center of mass lies outside the base of the shape. The defining point of that is the left most point of contact with the plane where the cylinder meets the cone. The COM lies along the dotted line denoting the height of the cone. As the cylinder increases in height the COM will move towards the cylinder until it is over that pivot point or to the left of it.

Comment: Question solved. It's along the cylinder